# MySQL - Error #1064 - DELETE records phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, null, phpmyadmin, relational-database

I have this sentence on `MySQL` database:

```
DELETE FROM `sugarcrm`.`elio_paciente_cstm` WHERE `elio_paciente_cstm`.`telefono_sishos_c` = NOT NULL
```

I need to delete , from the table `elio_paciente_cstm` in `sugarcrm`, all records which are not `NULL` in `telefono_sishos_c` row.

But it throws me this exception:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL' at line 1
```

I'm actually working on phpmyadmin, i could do this graphically, the easy way, but i like to have full control on what i'm doing to the database.

Anyone has a clue about this `NOT NULL` error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM `sugarcrm`.`elio_paciente_cstm` WHERE `elio_paciente_cstm`.`telefono_sishos_c` IS NOT NULL
```

You should not use relational operators when comparing null